# Best way to add unknown number of columns to Datatable and populate with data?

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I've looked into datatable.merge() and LINQ but not sure if Merge will work in this case and I'm just now starting to learn about LINQ.

In my project I have to join an unknown number of columns to an existing dataset.

I currently query the database and get records for each column that must be created and then a table of items and Id's that match the new columns and the existing dataset.

So the structure is like this:

```
foreach(Datarow row in newColumns.rows)
{
    originialDataTable.Columns.Add("\"Supplier: " + row["Supplier"] + "\r\n" +
                                        "ETA: " + row["ETADate"] + "\r\n" +
                                        "Shipped: " + row["ShipDate"] + "\r\n" +
                                        "Cartons: " + row["ContainerQty"] + "\r\n" +
                                        "Delivery Mode: " + row["ShipType"] + "\r\n" +
                                        "Container number: " + row["ContainerNumber"] + "\"");
                for (int c = 0; c < cmDataTable.Rows.Count; c++)
                {
                    for (int b = 0; b < originialDataTable.Rows.Count; b++)
                    {
                        string containerItem = cmDataTable.Rows[c]["POnumber"].ToString() + cmDataTable.Rows[c]["ItemNumber"].ToString();
                        string poItem = originialDataTable.Rows[b]["ponumber"].ToString() + originialDataTable.Rows[b]["stocknumber"];
                        if (containerItem == poItem && cmID == cmDataTable.Rows[c]["CMID"].ToString())
                        {
                            originialDataTable.Rows[b][position] = cmDataTable.Rows[c][2];
                        }
                    }
                } 
}
```

I know I should change the for loops to foreach but I'm not sure of the quality of the above code. Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: [DataColumnCollection.Add](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/52xzw8tf(v=vs.110).aspx) does not support adding multiple columns at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not completely clear regarding the requirements, but tried few things, check out the following code:

```
    DataTable dt = new DataTable(); // Create DataTable

    dt.Columns.Add("A", typeof(int)); // Add a Column
    dt.Columns["A"].DefaultValue = 5; // Set Column default value

    dt.Rows.Add(3); // Add a DataRow

    DataTable dt1 = new DataTable(); // Create DataTable

    dt1.Columns.Add("C", typeof(int)); // Add a Column
    dt1.Columns["C"].DefaultValue = 5; // Set Column default value

    dt1.Rows.Add(3); // Add a DataRow

    dt.Merge(dt1); // Merge dt1 into dt
```

The challenge that you would find in this kind of code is even when you might expect merged DataTable to contain `two columns and one row`, it would actually contain `2 rows`, where for merged column for each DataTable it will fill the default value (try running the code to understand), if I don't provide the `DefaultValue`, then it fills in the Null, following would be the result of the above code:

```
                  A   C
                  3   5
                  5   3
```

Now my understanding is this result would not be desirable, then I tried using some Linq Join, Full Outer Join to figure out if we can have a solution, but also seems unlikely since in a Join it traverse through all the rows and similar to Merge above add a default for all non existing Rows.

Only Solution I can think of is:

- Add all the columns to a new DataTable explicitly
- Run a for loop for number of Rows you want to insert, which can be from any of the DataTable (source) and copy the values inside the loop
- Default the unavailable values, for other Datatable until and unless we have exactly same number of rows

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I tried to explain the report as best as I could. I should note that the functionality and accuracy works 100% I guess I was looking for more of a code review. I didn't realize that there was a separate stack exchange for that.